# Overwriting and sending data within Selenium Header

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, header, overwrite

I'm using Selenium to **scrape**, but i got blocked. So I'm trying to overwrite the header and send data within it. I did it using `beautifulsoup` :

```
response = r.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

How can i translate this line to selenium please ?
Keep safe.

Comment: If you get blocked that's because of your ip. Use proxies instead

Comment: You can modify headers with [browsermpb-proxy](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization)